# Как сделать паузу в выполнении скрипта на php

Tags: php

У меня есть скрипт рассылающий почту.
Примерно такой, здесь не суть приводить полный код , вопрос не в этом.

```
foreach($list as $key){
    foreach($mail as $k){
         mail($email,$subject,$body);
         ....
    }
}
```

Как вы понимаете отправка письма не происходит  моментально, уж точно медленней чем выполняется этот код, по-этому на сервере забивается очередь  отправки.

Вопрос в том , как на месте многоточия реализовать паузу в 5- 10 секунд, как это вообще делается на php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Паузу можно сделать с помощью функции **sleep(секунды)**

Подробнее читайте тут - ***http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php***

Comment: У sleep аргумент в секундах, не миллисекундах. Если секунда слишком много - есть usleep с микросекундами.

Comment: пардон, да, точно) спасибо

Comment: спасибо спасибо ребята